# The meaning of "the dry yawn of water"

Tags: meaning

> Again the big gong beat, and a second time there was the rushing of naked feet on earth and ringing iron; the clatter of tools ceased. In the silence, men heard **the dry yawn of water** crawling over thirsty sand.”

This is from "The Bridge Builders" by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-bridge-builders.htm

I don't understand the meaning of
the dry yawn of water

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Comment: It does not really make sense to me either. From the context, I think they hear the sound of water flowing over dry sand in the distance. But it is not clear to me why Kipling refers to this as a "dry yawn of water."

Comment: @DrMoishePippik why don't you write an answer then?

Answer (score 1):

*Yawn* has multiple meanings, most stemming from the idea of opening, or *gaping* wide.

- [Lovecraft](https://americanliterature.com/author/h-p-lovecraft/short-story/the-transition-of-juan-romero): "a new abyss yawned indefinitely below the seat of the blast..."
- [Heller](https://www.azquotes.com/quote/917758): "There are yawning gulfs into which large chunks of me have fallen."

Comment: thank you very much foryour kind and clear answer! I understand the meanig of "yawn" as a metaphor.